# How to allow user to edit post with Django?

Tags: python, django, multi-table-inheritance

In my blog I decided to allow users to edit posts (I am using Django), but I am not sure what is the right implementation for my models to do that. Is a good idea to use multi-table inheritance as my code below? I also want to keep track of all the posts, originals as the every new edited as well.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    text = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s by %s" % (self.title, self.creation_date, self.user)

class Edit(Post):
    edited_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    editor = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s edited by %s" % (self.convention, self.login)
```

Comment: shouldn't you include your convention class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is version control. There are apps that can implement it. But if you want to do it yourself, then your `Edit` model must have a reference to the `Post` models. And must point to a specific post corresponding to the author of that edit. That necessarily means you have to create a `Post` instance every time a post is saved and you must point to that new instance from the Edit instance.

Something like this, but may need more work -

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    text = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s at %s by %s" % (self.title, self.creation_date, self.author.first_name)

class Edit(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s edited by %s" % (self.post.title, self.editor.first_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bibhas, using your suggestion means, that I have to re-create some fields inside the Edit class (title, text). isn't? For Example, this may look like that: Is it right? 

    `class Edit(models.Model):
        creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        editor = models.ForeignKey(User)
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
        title = models.TextField()
        text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s edited by %s" % (self.post.title, self.editor.first_name)`

Comment: No. You don't have to. Every edit points to the corresponding post object which already has those fields.